# How to complete remove the programm which is installed from binary

Tags: apt

im just installed a Packet Tracer programm from install script, not from the repo.And i want to delete this program, but this program is not a package, so the apt-get remove or purge or searching this app in synaptic/software center didn't work.
What can i do to delete all of this program files?

Comment: "install script," where is the link to that so we can inspect it? "installed from binary" Then why is this tagged apt? "What can i do to delete all of this program files? "  You copied it to somewhere. So "rm" it?

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the install script to see which artifacts it is creating and remove them manually. The program itself could create some artifacts at runtime (like a hidden directory in your homedir, for example `~/.packet-traces`).

From what I see here https://www.packet6.com/how-to-install-packet-tracer-on-ubuntu-linux/ this installation script also pulls some dependencies, so you may need to clear them as well.

In summary - there's some work to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky the package also contains an uninstall script; check the INSTALL or README or other documentation files, if there are any.